# Teaching Mercurial to SVNers on short notice

Tags: svn, mercurial

I just convinced two teammates in a class that I'm taking to start using Mercurial.  When I learned it a few years back I just read the [main site](http://mercurial.selenic.com/), asked questions on IRC, and played with it to figure it out.  However, given the pace of the class I don't think either of them are going to want to take the time to learn it that way.  I was thinking of recommending they look over [HgInit](http://hginit.com/) since they both have some Subversion background and that seems to be the intended audience.  However, does anyone have a better recommendation?

Has someone picked it up recently and found a specific source to be particularly useful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://nedbatchelder.com/text/hgsvn.html

http://wiki.pylonshq.com/display/pylonscookbook/Mercurial+for+Subversion+Users (Ignoring the Pylons-specific part, of course.)

Answer (score 3):

There is also Mercurial Kick Start guide at http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/

Answer (score 2):

HgInit is OK, but I also found [Mercurial: The Definitive Guide](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/) very useful. [Mercurial wiki](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Mercurial) is also worth browsing.